# How do I download an attachment from a discord channel?

Tags: python, discord.py

So, I have been trying to figure out how to download an attachment but I can't seem to figure out how. ctx.message.attachments[0].url doesnt work.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '-')

@client.command(name='setupwelcome', help='Sets up the welcome message.')
async def setup(ctx, msgid:int):
  await ctx.send("Enter welcome message here (If it is a multiline message, write the whole welcome message on a text editor and paste it on discord.")
  welcomeMessage = await client.wait_for("message")
  await ctx.send("Do you want to include an image in your welcome message?")
  decisionMessage = await client.wait_for("message")
  if decisionMessage.content.lower() == 'y':
    await ctx.send("Upload the image you want to use:")
    imageUsed = await ctx.message.attachments[0].url
```

I keep getting this in my console.

```
Ignoring exception in command setupwelcome:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/WelcomeBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 14, in setup
    imageUsed = await ctx.message.attachment[0].url
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'attachment'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/WelcomeBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/runner/WelcomeBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/WelcomeBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'attachment'
```

After fixing imageUsed I get an index error

```
Ignoring exception in command setupwelcome:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/WelcomeBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 14, in setup
    imageUsed = await ctx.message.attachments[0].url
IndexError: list index out of range

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/WelcomeBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/runner/WelcomeBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/WelcomeBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: What is your current output/behavior? It throws an error or just don't work as expected?

Comment: I keep getting an index error.

Comment: Add it to the question, and include your stacktrace to let others help you

Comment: I don't see that line anywhere in your code. Also, the error states that `Message` has no attribute `attachment`, which is true. Did you mean `attachments`?

Comment: So, that's my bad. I'll put the line in there. I didn't realize it wasn't there. I tried putting attachments but now I get an index error.

Answer (score 1):

`ctx.message` is a `Message` object created from the message that invoked the command. for example, if your user did `!setup <id>`, where `!` is the prefix for your command (assuming), that message is the `ctx.message`

when you do `ctx.message.attachments`, you are checking for attachments on the message that invoked the command of the bot.

I am still not sure what the `msgid` in there is for, but to wait for the image to be sent, you would need to use another `wait_for` with a check, that looks out if the message contains an attachment.

`Message.attachments` returns a `List[Attachment]` (list of Attachment objects found in the message)

if you try to index a `list` to an index where an element is not present in, it throws an `IndexError`.

Indexes start from `0`
eg:

```py
# for a string
# h   e   l   l   o 
# 0   1   2   3   4

# for a list/tuple
# elements: ['element_1', 'element_2', 'element_3', 'element_4']
# indexes:        0            1            2            3
```

Here is an example of `IndexError`

```py
>>> empty_list = []
>>> empty_list[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
# a working version of indexing
>>> empty_list = [1, 2, 3]
>>> empty_list[0]
1
```

Now, your code would look something like

```py
@client.command()
async def setup(ctx):
   ...
   ...
   ...

   attachment_message = await client.wait_for('message', check= lambda m: m.author == ctx.author and m.attachments) 
   # the check keyword argument checks if the message was sent by the same
   # person who executed the command and that message.attachments is not an
   # empty list
   attachment = attachment_message.attachments[0]
   # now do something with attachment
   # if you want to save url, use attachment.url to get the 
   # discord cdn url of the uploaded image
   # or if you want to save the image locally on your machine, 
   # then use await attachment.save()
   # do note, attachment can be of ANY type, a file, an image, 
   # do make sure to check that before saving
```

Read more about Attachments in the documentation of discord.py, If you are using `stable v1.7.3`, i.e you installed discord.py library with `pip install discord.py`, then refer to [discord.Attachment (stable)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Attachment)

if you are using `master 2.0.0a`, i.e, you install discord.py lib with `pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py`, then refer to [discord.Attachment (master)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Attachment)

Comment: Thanks for explaining this to me man and leaving the documentation here. I appreciate it.